# Chrome AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes to the REG_DWORD value of "0" to turn off auto-update?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-update

I need to stop chrome from updating for my test.

setting

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes

to the

> REG_DWORD

value of "0" doesn't work for me to stop chrome from auto-updating. any other suggestions?

I try to install chrome 75, but it updates to 76.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\UpdateDefault

to `"0"` and it worked for me :)